# Count how many rows you have in your db with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, count, phpmyadmin

Hellow,

I want to count how many rows i have in a table. I got a table (workstations) in my mysql database (phpmyadmin). I want to print it out, so ik can see how many workstations their are "active" in my environment

I've read many blogs about this, but all the things they propose are not working for me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use COUNT(*)

You can see here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name;
```

ex:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);
$rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
echo $rows[0];
```

Comment: and how do I print it out now? Something such as $count = Db::getResult('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM workstations');

<?php echo $count ?> ?

Comment: i have posted example ebove

Comment: what is the paramter $mysqli? Is that your database connections? i got an include file with my connection :)

Comment: $mysqli is connection object. I have  updated code above

Comment: Thanks! It works! is it also possible to $mysqli = include 'connect.php' ? i got a lot of tables that i want to print out ..

Comment: $mysqli = include 'connect.php' is wrong approach, but you can access connection object of connection.php file after including it in file...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM workstations where status = "active"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = DBCon::getCon()->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `issue`');
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo($result[0]['COUNT(*)']);
```

Using PDO, `DBCon::getCon()` is whatever your PDO Variable is.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know the total rows you have in your query, simply use the `COUNT()` function of MySQL like this:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM workstations WHERE status='active'";
```

Or if you want to see how many rows are being displayed with your PHP, you can use the easiest technic I know. Take a look at the sample below:

```
//your codes
.
.
.
$rowno = 1; //set row counter

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query), MYSQL_BOTH)){
     echo $rowno.") ".$row['station']."<br/>";
     $rowno++; //increment it when there is/more data following
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned the database name (say it is db )

Try this query in the mysql console in the phpmyadmin

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `db`.`workstations` where `workstation`.`status` = "active"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it by using SQL Aggregate function count "COUNT".

Refer this example code:

```
<?php
$host_name = "YOUR HOST NAME";
$database = "DATABASE NAME";
$user_name = "USERNAME";
$password = "PASSWORD";
$conn = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);
if (mysqli_connect_error($conn)) {
    die('error in connection');
} else {
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `workstations` WHERE `status` = '1'");
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    echo $result[0];
}
```

> `status` = 1 or `status` = 'active'

will ensure that you get the count of active worksattions from your database, but make sure to add `status` column in your table.